# How much entropy does BIP39 have?

Tags: wallet, bip39, security, randomness

How much entropy does BIP39 have?

How long would brute forcing take?

Can a 2nd factor be included on a wallet, to lock, unlock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86803/36633)

It seems a very well resourced attacker would be able to find a used private key for 128bit seed.
This would be an attack on all keys in the network, not yours specifically.
For 256bit seed, it should be infeasible.

Answer (score 2):

128 bit for 11 seed word and 256 for 27 seed word
for 128 bit 1.02 x 10^18 years.

Comment: I have 12 and 24 word options here.

Comment: what is your wallet ?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that if you generate a wallet with the help of ***cardano-wallet*** utility you will be proposed two options: **general-factor 24-word seed** (2048²⁴ or 2²⁶⁴ possible combinations) and optional **second-factor 12-word seed** (2048¹² or 2¹³² possible combinations).

That's a real nightmare for a hacker because it's practically impossible to brute force it.